# Подключение к базе данных из Android-приложения c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

Подскажите, как можно подключиться к базе данных firebird из Android-приложения на c#

Answer (score 1):

Если предполагается, что БД хранится на сервере, то подключаться желательно через API по защищённому протоколу. Прямого "общения" между БД и приложением по сети быть не должно, хотя бы из соображений безопасности.

Если Вы пытаетесь использовать FireBird как локальную СУБД, то либо экспериментировать со сборками (возможно, найдёте что-то в репозитории или ещё где-то) или тоже каким-то образом экспериментировать, но уже с родным клиентом под Android на Java.

А, вообще для локального хранения данных советую заменить FireBird на SQLite. Сильно упростите себе жизнь.